# ember-cli-mirage and babel error

Tags: ember.js, babeljs, ember-cli-mirage

I am following this tutorial: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/tutorial/installing-addons/

and when i get to adding ember-cli-mirage it comes up with a build error and wont load the app:

```js
Richards-MacBook-Air:super-rentals rpt$ ember s
WARNING: Node v8.9.1 has currently not been tested against Ember CLI and may result in unexpected behaviour.

Just getting started with Ember? Please visit http://localhost:4200/ember-getting-started to get going

Livereload server on http://localhost:49154
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:615:25)
 code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
File: ember-cli-mirage/utils/inflector.js
The Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel] failed with:
SyntaxError: ember-cli-mirage/utils/inflector.js: Unexpected token (4:14)
export { singularize, pluralize } from 'ember-inflector';

export { Ember.String.capitalize as capitalize, Ember.String.camelize as camelize, Ember.String.dasherize as dasherize, Ember.String.underscore as underscore };
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:76:33)
    at Parser.pp.parseExportSpecifiers (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:772:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExport (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:701:28)
    at Parser.parseExport (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:713:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:115:90)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:655:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:30:21)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/index.js:70:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:45:50)
    at Object.exports.default (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/parse.js:36:18)
    at File.parse (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:574:40)
    at File.parseCode (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:691:20)
    at /Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:167:12
    at File.wrap (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:639:16)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:165:17)
    at /Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/lib/parallel-api.js:123:26
    at initializePromise (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:567:5)
    at new Promise (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1039:33)
    at Object.transformString (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/lib/parallel-api.js:117:12)
    at Babel.transform (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:110:22)
    at Babel.processString (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:216:15)
    at Promise.then.result.output (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/lib/strategies/persistent.js:41:23)
    at initializePromise (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:567:5)
    at new Promise (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1039:33)
    at /Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/lib/strategies/persistent.js:40:18
    at tryCatch (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)


The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at Babel.Plugin (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at Babel.Filter [as constructor] (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/index.js:64:10)
    at new Babel (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:37:10)
    at EmberApp._addonTree (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:910:29)
    at EmberApp._processedVendorTree (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:944:20)
    at EmberApp._processedExternalTree (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:975:21)
    at EmberApp.appAndDependencies (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1071:30)
    at EmberApp.javascript (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1201:34)
    at EmberApp.toArray (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1606:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1628:30)
    at module.exports (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/ember-cli-build.js:23:14)
    at Class.setupBroccoliBuilder (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:74:19)
    at Class.init (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:54:10)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:32:18)
    at new Class (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:32:33)
    at Class.run (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/serve.js:15:19)
    at /Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/commands/serve.js:76:24
    at tryCatch (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:13)
    at /Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:606:14
    at flush (/Users/rpt/projects/super-rentals/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to whats going wrong?

Im using ember 2.8.0 and using the latest version of ember-cli-mirage.

Please bare in mind I am really new to ember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are starting with Ember 2.8? Unless there is, I would suggest fully removing Ember-CLI (`npm uninstall -g ember-cli`) and starting over with Ember 3.0.

The reason I suggest that is that the errors you are seeing there look to be due to Babel upgrades that Mirage is expecting in the latest version of Mirage but that don’t exist in the older version of Ember that you have installed.

Comment: I am trying to learn 2.8.0 as this is what the project i will be working on will be using. I dont suppose you would know what version of mirage i should use? or would i just have to install each version and see which one works?